# The image must be an image

Tags: php, laravel, web, file-upload, frameworks

So here it is.
I want to edit a data in database, it work perfectly if I upload an image every time I fill the form. but the problem raised when I edited another data and didn't upload an image instead of filling it with old image data (which is the file in my local) from database which is a string. the image validation makes the error was raised.

here my image validation
`'image' => 'image|max:1024'`

if I just put it like this `'image' => 'max:1024'`, it will run well because it wouldn't check if it's an image, but it will generate a problem where user start using edit data function to inject another unwanted code.

here is the update code

```
use WithFileUploads;

public $productId;
public $title;
public $description;
public $price;
public $image;
public $imageOld;

protected $listeners = [
    'editProduct' => 'editProductHandler'
];

public function update()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'description' => 'required|max:180',
            'image' => 'image|max:1024'
        ]);

        if ($this->productId) {
            $product = Product::find($this->productId);

            $image = '';

            if ($this->image) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($product->image);

                $imageName = \Str::slug($this->title, '-')
                    . '-'
                    . uniqid()
                    . '.' . $this->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            
                $this->image->storeAs('public', $imageName, 'local');

                $image = $imageName;
            } else {
                $image = $product->image;
            }

            $product->update([
                'title' => $this->title,
                'price' => $this->price,
                'description' => $this->description,
                'image' => $image
            ]);

            $this->emit('productUpdated');
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't check the old data from database, its image or not. Show me your update code

Comment: already added it @STA

Comment: I think the problem in your request, did you add  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your from?

Comment: of course mate, that's why if I edit the data and upload submit it with image it will run perfectly but if I edited another data and let the image with old data string from database, the error was raised @STA

Comment: whats the output of `dd($request->all());` ?

Comment: the image return with null somehow
`array:7 [▼
  "id" => "XtTulntjqpZYQWusF6Uf"
  "data" => array:6 [▼
    "productId" => 58
    "title" => "laptop baru"
    "description" => "laptop mac"
    "price" => 20000000
    "image" => null
    "imageOld" => "http://laravel-livewire.test/storage/laptop3-5f16743473c2b.png"
  ]
  "name" => "product.update"
  "checksum" => "3e48f7c9130e508bca49c660659e2f30a26982b2e4c27c7de6f06adfd5d5c0b0"
  "locale" => "en"
  "children" => []
  "actionQueue" => array:1 [▶]
]`

Comment: do you please update the image picture

Comment: `array:7 [▼
  "id" => "XtTulntjqpZYQWusF6Uf"
  "data" => array:6 [▼
    "productId" => 58
    "title" => "laptop baru"
    "description" => "laptop mac"
    "price" => 20000000
    "image" => "livewire-file:QqHLkBcF1kMedHOPgLWJ7PuUkjuA19-metac2lnbmF0dXJlLnBuZw==-.png"
    "imageOld" => "http://laravel-livewire.test/storage/laptop3-5f16743473c2b.png"
  ]
  "name" => "product.update"
  "checksum" => "a050b13aa2fad89085910b6cf109c08555e8c00a291bb990cb275f8e755458a6"
  "locale" => "en"
  "children" => []
  "actionQueue" => array:1 [▶]
]` 

thats

Comment: the `image` is not null in your request

Comment: that's if I added image, if  I only fill another field it's the first code I show u

Comment: If you not add the image, then what is the output of dd?

Comment: the first one mate, look at before you ask to update the image picture

Comment: try to change `public function update()` to `public function update(Request $request)` keep me updated